# network error while fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I would like to know how I can solve this: I am using windows, when I run a new project, for example:

```
Rails new project_name
```

I get this error:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...........
Network error fetching
https://rubygems.org/quick/marshal.4.8/json-1.8.3-java.gemspec.rz
```

Comment: Can you edit this question and copy-paste the *exact* error message? all the spaces are confusing me.

Comment: Ready, I edited that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions to this issue.

1. Your network isn't working right now or has a bad connection. Make sure wifi is working, connect to an ethernet cable, or just wait.
2. Rubygems is having some sort of issue. Check at https://status.rubygems.org/
3. Bundler and/or Rubygems have a bug.

Upgrade `gem` and `bundler` to the latest version:

```
gem update --system
gem update bundler
```

If `gem update --system` fails, you may have an old enough version of RubyGems that you need a special upgrader:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
gem update bundler
```

Depending on how if it was originally installed with sudo, you may need to run these commands with sudo as well.

If you are *still* having issues, I've run out of answers and you'll need to sacrifice a small puppy on the alter of BundlerWhatHaveIDoneToDeserveThis.